# I need help understanding how to prove partial correctness

Tags: correctness-proof, software-engineering, program-correctness, hoare-logic

Please help me understand how I would prove the partial correctness of the below pseudocode with respect to the following predicates:

Pre: `{n>=0}`

Post: `{a^2 <= n and n < (a+1)^2)`

That is,

```
{Pre}
begin
   x:= 0;
   y:= 1;
   z:= 1;
   while y <= n do
      x:= x+1;
      z:= z+2;
      y:= y+z;
   a:= x;
end
{Post}
```

An explanation would be much appreciated. I've read various PPTs and PDFs and still can't fully make sense of how to do this.

From what I can tell, I *think* that if the code is executed satisfying the precondition, then everything holds true. The problem is that I'm not sure how to formally prove that.

Considering Hoare's logic, would the Composition rule be applied here? Would each line of pseudocode be a consecutive "program" in the Hoare Triple? I guess one of the things confusing me is how to solve for multiple lines of code. Most examples I've come across are more simplified: `{ x + 1 = 43 } y := x + 1 { y = 43 }`

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  It's hard to know how to help you, as the question doesn''t give us much to go on: it doesn't tell us what has you confused, or what partial approaches you've made, or what approaches you've considered, or what your thoughts are.  We want to help you understand concepts, not do an exercise for you.  Can you try editing the question to ask about some conceptual uncertainty that is preventing you from doing this exercise, and show us how far you were able to get on your own?

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for the response. By no means am I looking to have anyone complete an exercise for me, I'm just not sure where to begin I guess. A walk-through or explanation of a different problem to help me understand would also be appreciated.

Comment: You have a piece of code, a set of preconditions and a set of postconditions. With only that, you cannot prove anything. You also need *inference rules*. If you started studying this from a text, it probably also includes the "Hoare Logic" for the language you're using. Is that so? You could post the inference rules and tell us what you have tried (how did you try to use them?)

Comment: @JBenzie: *"if the code is executed satisfying the precondition, that everything holds true"* -- it's almost that. *IF* the precondition is true before the code is executed, *THEN* the postcondition will be true immediately after the execution -- *EXCEPT* that the code may not stop executing (and this is why it's called "partial" correctness -- we don't require termination).

Comment: @Jay: Thank you for your responses. Unfortunately, I do not have any inference rules. This piece of pseudocode is all that was given to me. I just want to reiterate the fact that I'm not looking for someone to just give me a solution, I'd like to actually understand how to do it. I included this pseudocode because it is the only thing I have. So is it not possible to prove this without inference rules?

Comment: @JBenzie: it may be helpful to look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic) on Hoar Logic. Section 3 explains the rules and gives some examples. *However*, note that for a different language, the inference rules would be different. (But I can see that the language you're using is essentially the same that Hoare used originally, and the same on the Wikipedia article)

Comment: @JBenzie: by the way, please double-check your pseudo-code. You use a `begin..end` pair for the whole probram, but seems to use indentation-delimited blocks for the while body. It would be better to keep block delimiting syntax uniform (including `begin..end` in the while body would fix that)

Comment: @Jay: Looking at the Wikipedia article, would the Composition rule be applied here? Would each line of pseudocode be a consecutive "program" in the Hoare Triple? I guess one of the things confusing me is how to solve for multiple lines of code. Most examples I've come across are more simplified: `{ x + 1 = 43 }   y := x + 1   { y = 43 }`

Comment: @JBenzie: Yes, exactly! Use the composition rule for each pair of commands. But see that you may split "two commands" in any way that fits you: one line folowed by all others, or half the lines followed by the other half.  One line at a time makes it easier.

Comment: @Jay: Thank you for your time and patience. It's beginning to make sense to me now. Just took a little while for me to get my head wrapped around it...